# How to load only some libraries in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I have a project with many dependencies, and I found gdb really slow at startup... during this startup, I see some "loading [...].so" that hang for about 20s. Is there a way to load only libraries I'm interested in debugging or blacklist those I don't care ?

Comment: provide some context, like technology or language.

Comment: isn't gdb quite universal ? I mean... I have a program, and I want to debug a library whit this program using it. So I don't car of the program itself, nor other dependencies of this program... how to speedup the startup of gdb?

Comment: The program being debugged can be written in Ada, C, C++, Objective-C, Pascal (and many other languages)

Comment: C++, but why is it relevant here ?

Comment: relevant information might help to get better answer